# dynamically setting a makefile variable using awk

Tags: makefile, awk

I have a variable stoppoint defined in my makefile.
I want to set this variable using the output of awk from withing my Makefile.

I want to see if the second argument is main or not

I have tried:

```
stoppoint = $(awk '$$2 ~ /main/ {print $$1}' file)  
stoppoint = "$(awk '$$2 ~ /main/ {print $$1}' file)"  
stoppoint = 'awk '$$2 ~ /main/ {print $$1}' file'
awk '$$2 ~ /main/ {print $$1}' file > stoppoint
awk '$$2 ~ /main/ {print $$1}' file > $(stoppoint)
```

However, I am unable to set this variable. 
Kindly tell me how one can set a variable using awk inside a Makefile

PS: On command line, the awk command gives me the output I desire...

Thanks,
Tejas

Comment: I suspect your problem is that each line in the Makefile invokes a new shell. So if you assign the variable in one line, it will not be defined in the next line since that command will run in a new shell.

Comment: seems a legit reasoning! I will try that too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple:
Makefile assumed the format

target: dependencies followed on the next line by actions after a `TAB`

In the above case, we cannot set a variable in the next line after a `TAB` because it assumes it to be an action. Just remove the `TAB` and set it.
That would solve the issue

Comment: I don't understand. If you remove the TAB, the target will end (tested). Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 5):

You have to use french quotes (``)

Here is an example:

```
all:
    @a=`echo "hello world!!" | awk '{print $0;}' -`; echo $$a;
```

Comment: HI, It does not work :( I use: @a = `awk '$$2 ~ /main/ {print $$1;}' file`; echo $$a. It says: a: command not found, when I define a earlier as a=0. When I dont define it, it still fails :(. With french quotes, ofcourse.

Comment: It worked for me using a=\`awk '...' file\`. I'm using bash in ubuntu. Could you give me a file example and desired output?

Comment: Are you doing it inside a Makefile? 1. you cant use "$1", you have to use $$1, etc. 2. It does not allow me to set variables on the fly. In general what is the procedure to set a variable dynamically in a Makefile?

Comment: Using bash it works, but I want it to work from within a Makefile, that changes a lot of rules, I guess

Comment: My example was inside a Makefile `all: @a=...`

Comment: I think I have found your mistake. You have to put a=... without spaces between "a" and "=", and between "=" and the french quote.

Comment: Did you get it removing spaces in the assignment?

Comment: Ok,Thanks, I tried that. Now instead of giving me an error, it goes ahead, but it has an empty string in place of the variable. I do: @variable=`awk '$$2 ~ /<main>/ {print $$1}' file`; echo $$variable. Is this wrong?

Comment: Then the assignment is ok, it might be a problem in awk.
I created a dummy file with 2 lines and it was ok, it showed me the expected output. Probably $2 is not matching with the AWK pattern.

Comment: :) The same command on the command line gives me the value: awk '$2 ~ /<main>/ {print $1}' file gives me an output 0x60000078. Its messy using awk from inside a Makefile ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an `eval` structure like this:

```
.PHONY: default
default: all

rule1:
    $(eval GLOBAL_VAR=`awk '$$2 ~ /main/ {print $$1}' file`)

all: rule1
    @echo "The global var is: $(GLOBAL_VAR)"
```

The [eval](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) evaluates the string as makefile syntax.  Here, it sets the GLOBAL_VAR variable to the result of the shell function call, which in turn gets printed out in another rule to illustrate it's global.

Answer (score 1):

Right now the way I do it is:

```
@awk '$$2 ~ /main/ {print $$1}' inputfile > DUMP
```

It gives me a value `0x60000078` inside dump

And to use it:

```
@echo -e "set pc $(shell cat DUMP)" > testfile
```

This seems to solve my issue, But I hope someone can point me to a better solution.

Thanks,

Tejas

Comment: Adding shell also solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

Another option for using awk in a makefile, use of $$:

```
VERSION=`awk '/version:/{print $$NF}' charts/Chart.yaml`
```

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to work around this problem was using the keyword `shell` when calling `awk`, like that:

```
VARIABLE="$(shell awk '__awk script__' file-awk-processes)"
```

Hope it helps!